# How do I send an xml request and receive an xml response in django Python?

Tags: django, xml, python-3.x, django-views, httplib

How to make a xml http request and get xml response in django python?

request

```
<RDVMessage>
<Header> {Authorization:'54873' } </Header>
<Body>
    <Request>
       <CustomerID> 12345</ CustomerID >
    </Request>
</Body>
</RDVMessage>
```

Response:

```
<RDVMessage>
<Header> {Authorization:'54873'} </Header>
<Body>
    <Response>
    <ID> 56789</ID >
    </Response>
</Body>
</RDVMessage>
```

Comment: You can use the Django REST API and use XML as serialization.

Comment: Thanks you for the response.Can u comment me with small example